# Multiple contact form 7 fields in one google sheet cell?

Tags: contact-form-7

I'm using contact form to accept small one letter inputs from people and putting them together as words. I have something like 7 text fields for a 7 letter word. I'm saving these submissions to google sheets

I'm trying to put the letters together as they entered and make it a word. something like [text-1-1][text-1-2][text-1-3] and so on.. where each field just spits a letter.

However, when i submit the form, these letters won't come into the google sheet. stays empty.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Yep i just did that

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this.. For those who are stuck/get stuck with this issue for now and for the future..

You can use the concatenate() function in google sheets.

For example:

concatenate(CELL1,CELL2,CELL3) and all those cell blocks will be added to one cell